# Highlight current item with all previous item in a menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: menubar navigation]

Here i attached my menubar.My web page is fully scrollbar page shift type(i.e,a single page containing six pages that would be scrollable on clicking menu items). While i click my menu item the highlight of my menu item could be like as in the attached image.Still now i work with a single menu item highlight as for current page,but here my need is while i click my fourth menu then the current menu item with all previous menu items also need to be highlighted.How can i proceed this?

Comment: Lovely picture, but can we see some code?

Comment: What about a live example?

Comment: Come on guys since when we are mind readers those above me are right. Use that http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assumption of this markup:

```
<span class="menuitem">Howdy</span>
<span class="menuitem">Howdy</span>
<span class="menuitem">Howdy</span>
<span class="menuitem">Howdy</span>
<span class="menuitem">Howdy</span>
```

this CSS:

```
.menuitem{border-bottom: 4px solid #888888;}
.menuActive{border-bottom: 4px solid blue;}
```

this code:

```
$('.menuitem').click(function(){
    $('.menuitem').removeClass('menuActive');
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('menuActive');
});
```

this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vE6yW/

EDIT: Relevent to jQuery version 1.8 and 1.9+.

In jQuery version 1.8, the `addBack()` method was created and in version 1.9 the `andSelf()` was removed.  For jQuery 1.8 and forward, please use:

```
$('.menuitem').click(function(){
    $('.menuitem').removeClass('menuActive');
    $(this).prevAll().addBack().addClass('menuActive');
});
```

In this code, the effect would be the same.  `addBack()` also implimented a selector to reduce the elements added back to the selection group in case that is needed.

Comment: @Tadeck - better CSS, given, but I supposed that would be easy to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab and assume this is close to what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/cxndW/

I'm using a solid border to achieve the effect, but you should be able to do it with background images or border images.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
</ul>​
```

CSS (note it is completely generic, you'll want to use classes or ids to make this more specific):

```
ul{
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:1em;
    float:left;
}
li{
    float:left;
    padding:.1em 0;
    border-bottom:solid 5px #ccc; /* base state, grey */
    cursor:pointer;
}
li + li{
    padding-left:1em;
}
ul:hover li,                  /* all list items when the ul is hovered */
ul.active li,                 /* or all list items when the ul is "active" */
ul.active:hover li{           /* an override for below */
    border-bottom-color:#34f; /* become blue */
}
li:hover ~ li,                /* all list items after the hovered list item */
ul li.active ~ li,            /* all list items after the active list item */
ul.active:hover li:hover ~ li{ /* an override for when the list is active and hovered */
    border-bottom:solid 5px #ccc; /* back to grey */
}
```

There is also a bit of trivial jQuery in the demo that sets the li class to active when clicked (clearing each other active li class).

Comment: Also, normally I would request that you show what effort you put in, but this question was interesting enough for me to try and do.